Minimal autoinstall.yaml to install authorized keys, getting subiquity/Error/load_autoinstall_data
I am trying to create the minimal autoinstall.yaml that will let me install SSH authorized keys.
This is my autoinstall.yaml:
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_US
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    username: ubuntu
    realname: "Ubuntu User"
  ssh:
    install-server: yes
    authorized-keys:
      - "..."
    allow-pw: no

I have added this to the ubuntu 22.04 server installation USB stick. Upon booting it fails with:
subiquity/Error/load_autoinstall_data
I can enter a shell and cat /autoinstall.yaml and see the file is there as expected.
No clue what's wrong. Thanks for any help!

install-server and allow-pw are boolean. Instead of yes/no it is true/false:
install-server: true
allow-pw: false

authorized-keys should be a list of strings for example:
authorized-keys: ["ssh-rsa ADAQABAAA...xyz@abc","ssh-rsa AuWTSrq6...test@domain"]

ssh in Autoinstall configuration reference manual

In YAML, "yes" and "true" are equivalent: https://yaml.org/type/bool.html
And what I showed is also valid list syntax in YAML.

Indenting under the top-level autoinstall: key is only supported with ubuntu 24.04 and later. Removing that key and shifting the contents up one level is required for ubuntu 22.04 (and earlier).
